# How get breadcrumbs not only when app is crash but when I have custom error

Tags: google-analytics, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, crash-reports, visual-studio-app-center

MS AppCenter and Google Analytics get breadcrumbs only when the app is crashed. But I need these logs when the app has some custom error. Maybe somebody knows how to get these breadcrumbs by error or some lib what can do this.